# Existence and uniqueness for fractional parabolic equation with transport term

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde, semigroups-of-operators

Let us consider the problem
\begin{equation}
  \begin{cases}
    u_t+(-\Delta)^{\sigma}u+\mathrm{div}(a(t,x)u) = 0 & \text{in } \mathbb{R}^n \times [0, T) \\
    u(x,0)=u_0(x) & \text{in } \mathbb{R}^n
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
with $\sigma \in (0,1)$, $u_0 \in L^p(\mathbb R^n)$, and $a \in L^q((0,T)\times \mathbb R^n)$ for some $\infty > p,q \ge 1$ (with suitable restrictions if needed). Is a result on existence and uniqueness of solutions known?

Comment: For what it's worth, with a time-homogeneous coefficient $a(t,x)=a(x)$, and with an additional coefficient at $(-\Delta)^\sigma u$, this problem was studied by Alex Kulig and co-authors, e.g. in [DOI:10.1214/16-AIHP796](https://doi.org/10.1214/16-AIHP796) and in [DOI:10.1016/j.spa.2018.03.010](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.spa.2018.03.010).

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Thanks! But it seems that the coefficients are much more than $L^p$ in that paper

Comment: Yes, that's true: their parametrix construction requires certain Hölder continuity of $a(t,x)=a(x)$ when $\sigma \leqslant \tfrac12$, and boundedness of $a(x)$ if $\sigma > \tfrac12$. Other works cided there also need Hölder regularity, I think. With $a(t,x)$ so rough, I suppose not much is known, but I am no expert.